# Kendo Grid Detail too wide

Tags: kendo-ui, resize, kendo-grid

http://dojo.telerik.com/EPiPi

My example has a detail Grid that is larger (wider) than the original grid (assuming you have a 1920p or smaller monitor).

When I scroll to the right the detail grid continues on but is not displayed, hence I am looking for a way to enlarge the original grid when the detail is expanded.
I.E. I want the detail to be properly scrollable when expanded (which is not the case currently).

I have found following resources but do not know how I could apply them. Maybe I can do the following:

- On expand read the sizes of all columns in the detail and calculate a sum
- Resize the grid to that width

  - to my knowledge it is 'only' possible to resize columns
  - so i would have to go through all columns and resize them individually so their sum equals the detail column sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your problem, but I think your detailrow grid should be scrollable (scrollable: true) and you also need to give a width to ShipAddress column to make it visible.